# Find decrease values in table sql query

Tags: sql, db2

i have a table like this. If times increas i expect to increase Rating column but sometimes rating column decrease. I want to find how many times decrease this table.  In this example rating column 2 times decrease (4-->2 and 3--> 1 ) i want to this 2 number in query. Also times column every time increase.How can i write this situation's sql query.  (note: i am using DB2 DBMS)

```
Rating times
1      20.09.2016  
2      21.09.2016
3      22.09.2016
4      23.09.2016
2      24.09.2016
3      25.09.2016
1      26.09.2016
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is that sample table data? Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: do you have exactly 1 rating per day? are there any gaps in dates?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS COUNT_OF_TIMES_RATING_GOT_DECREASED
  FROM
 (
    SELECT rating, 
           times,
           rating - LEAD( rating, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY times ) AS diff_rating
      FROM table 
  )
WHERE diff_rating > 0;
```

Comment: Hi, which dbms are you using ? LEAD and OVER is a function i haven't seen yet this functions. Can you rewrite this query db2 or mssql?

Comment: this query should also work in sql server 2012 and later versions

Comment: Could you write db2 version i can find lead,over function ? it will be good for me.

Comment: @altandogan . . . "Recent" versions of DB2 have supported window functions for years:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html.

Answer (score 0):

Without those functions being available, e.g. with the DB2 for i, the following should suffice [easily omitting the *fluff* I add to make a *pretty* report, and/or optionally *correcting* my inclusion of the row_number to reveal the from/to instead of showing the "times" values that exhibit that decreasing transition]:

```
create table ratings 
( "rating" for r dec 
, "times"  for t date
)
;
insert into  ratings values
/*    Rating times      */ 
  (   1 ,   '20.09.2016'  )
, (   2 ,   '21.09.2016'  )
, (   3 ,   '22.09.2016'  )
, (   4 ,   '23.09.2016'  )
, (   2 ,   '24.09.2016'  )
, (   3 ,   '25.09.2016'  )
, (   1 ,   '26.09.2016'  )
;
with            
  ord_ratings as
   ( select row_number() over(order by "times) as rn
          , "rating"            
     from ratings               
   )                            
select 'From'       as "From"   
     , dec(a.rn, 6) as rn_a     
     , 'to'         as "to"     
     , dec(b.rn, 6) as rn_b     
     , a."rating"   as rating_a 
     , '-->'        as "-->"    
     , b."rating"   as rating_b 
from ord_ratings a      
join ord_ratings b      
  on a.rn = ( b.rn - 1 )
 and b."rating" < a."rating"
; -- a likeness of the report from the above query:
"From"     RN_A   "to"     RN_B   RATING_A  "-->"  RATING_B
 From         4    to         5         4    -->         2 
 From         6    to         7         3    -->         1 
********  End of data  ********
```